# Keepinig Ruby OOP DRY

Tags: ruby

I am relatively new to ruby. Is it possible that initializing an object will automatically initialize its parent class? I know you can call super manually to call the superclass' initialize method, but does this happen automatically if you do not explicitly call super?

In java it happens. When you initialize a java object its parent class' objects are automatically initialized and its parent class' constructors are automatically called.

If this does not happen in ruby, does it mean a new parent class object is not automatically created (initialized) along with child class?

If that's the case, what would be the best OOP way to solve my problem?

Class B is a child of A. A has an attribute Xresult. B's initialize is passed object X and we need to set Xresult in A by using the object X  passed to B's initialize.

One way would be to pass X to A's initialize where we can get Xresult out of X and set the attribute. However to do that I will have to do a super(X) in B's initialize. This won't be dry. I have many B like children.

Comment: Can Xresult be a method? You can call method instead of reaching out to the super's attributes.

Comment: But still I would have to call this method repitatively in every B.

Comment: "does it mean a new parent class object is not automatically created" - there's no "parent object", you know. It's all the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but does this happen automatically if do not explicitly call super.

No, it doesn't happen automatically if the subclass has its own `initialize` method. However, if the subclass doesn't define its own `initialize` method, then it will inherit the one from the parent class.

> One way would be to pass X to A's initialize where we can get Xresult out of X and set the attribute. However to do that i will have to do a super(X) in B's initialize. ( This wont be dry. I have many B like childs )

I think that this is a perfectly acceptable solution. Duplicating a single line of code like `super x` is unavoidable.

---

That being said, you could just have A's initialize method call a method that you define in B like so:

```
class A
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
    initialize_subclass if respond_to?(:initialize_subclass)
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize_subclass
    puts 'doing B-specific stuff'
  end
end

B.new(5)
A.new(6)
```

Comment: Will accept this as a answer if no one else responds.

Comment: I think the proposed solution with ```initialize_subclass``` is bad design. Ruby already has a construct for this behavior (```initialize``` and ```super```) . This is asking for trouble because now implementors need to know that they MUST NOT implement an initializer.
. Also checking if a potential subclass added a method and then magically calling it seems wrong to me as well.

Comment: Nevertheless I am writing all the implementors and the superclass myself. And the answer helps me learn something new. Accepting it.

Comment: @Rpant "I'm writing everything myself" is irrelevant. You yourself might forget that you need to not implement initialize (in, say, 6 months after not looking at the code). This is bad OOP advice.

Comment: If you were going down this road, instead of the `if` clause I suggest creating a default `initialize_subclass` method within the base superclass `class A` containing an error message so that at least if you forget to implement an `initialize subclass` method in any new subclass a useful error message will tell you what's up.

Answer (score 2):

**Java**

Even in Java you will need to call the super constructor manually as soon as there is no "no-args constructor".

**Ruby**

In Ruby you need to call `super` manually in subclasses `initialize`. That seems perfectly OK to me as you do only override the initializer if you need to do additional work, that can not be done in super class initializer.
Unlike in Java the call to `super` does not need to be on the first line of the `initializer`

```
class Child < Parent
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @b = b
    @something = @a + @c
    super(a)
  end
end
```

I edit the question to clarify a comment by *Rpant*: *"Looks like in ruby , methods are simply copied from base class to derived class"*

No, methods are not **copied** from parent to child class. The `initialize` method is a normal method in ruby, it has no special behavior like in Java. If you provide one, then it will be called. It is not needed to initialize the object or allocation memory, this is done in `.new`(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-new).

The reason `initialize` of your super class is not called lies in the method lookup path:

When a method is called on a object, then the class hierarchy is searched. As soon as the method is found, the search stops and the method is called. From there on, it is your responsibility to call `super` if required.

Comment: But the point is Java will always try to initialize super class and will throw a runtime exception if there is no zero-arg constructor in super class in the case you said. Your answer was still helpful. Looks like in ruby , methods are simply copied from base class to derived class.

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

To complement other answers: ruby's `initialize` is **not** a constructor. It is just an ordinary method, same as all other methods you might have on the class. The only difference is that `initialize` is being called when you `new` an object (as a part of object creation procedure).

If you had this method in `B`:

```
class B < A
  def hello
    puts 'whatever'
  end
end
```

You wouldn't expect it to automatically call parent's `hello`, would you? So there's your answer.